# After Insert trigger in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these tables:

- TableParent (id, name, paidamt, gstamt)
- TableChild (id, parentid, paidamt, gstamt)

After inserting the record in the child table with same `parentid`:

```
update tableparent(paidamt, gstamt) 
values (sum(TableChild.paidamt), sum(TableChild.gstamt)) 
where  TableChild.parentid =  TableParent.id
```

I tried this query but it's not working...

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateValueInExpance 
ON ExpPaymentRecipt 
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @pid INT;

    SELECT @pid = id FROM inserted

    DECLARE @tbl TABLE (tds MONEY, amt MONEY)

    INSERT INTO @tbl (tds, amt) 
        SELECT TDS, AmountPaid 
        FROM ExpPaymentRecipt 
        WHERE ExpPaymentRecipt.EID = pid;

    UPDATE Expanses 
    SET PaidAmt = SUM(@tbl.amt),  
        TDSAmt = SUM(@tbl.tds) 
    FROM @tbl 
    WHERE Expanses.id = pid
END
```

> ** This is how I wanted **... Thanks, Everyone for your support

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateValueInExpance] ON [dbo].[ExpPaymentRecipt]  AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS BEGIN 
declare @id int;    
select top(1) @id = i.EID FROM inserted i;
if(@id is null)
select top(1) @id = i.EID FROM deleted i;

UPDATE p SET 
p.PaidAmt = (Select SUM(AmountPaid) from ExpPaymentRecipt where EID = @id), 
p.TDSAmt = (Select SUM(TDS) from ExpPaymentRecipt where EID = @id) 
FROM Expanses p where p.ID = @id END;
```

Comment: Could you explain what you need with more details?

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @pid = id FROM inserted` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Don't you miss an @ sign in a last trigger's line? Should it be `WHERE Expanses.id = @pid`?

Comment: `after insert or update update` ... `= @pid` (two times is `= pid`) ... ExpPaymentRecipt, Expanses, TableParent or TableChild - use constant names of tables and columns

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Triggers:

read about triggers here: [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

HINT: go with `AFTER INSERT` trigger on child table

Answer (score 0):

Based on the *description* of your problem, your trigger should look like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateValueInExpance ON ExpPaymentRecipt  AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN  
    UPDATE p
        SET gstamt = gstamt + child_paidamt
        FROM tableparent p JOIN
             (SELECT i.parentid, SUM(c.paidamt) as child_paidamt
              FROM inserted i
              GROUP BY i.parentid
             ) c
             ON c.parentid = p.id;
END;
```

It is unclear how this relates to your sample code, because the sample code is quite different from your definition (the tables are named differently, you are setting two columns, etc.).

You are making one fundamental error in assuming that `inserted` has only one row.  That is a big mistake and will lead to bugs in the code.

Comment: Thanks,
It helps me to understand, how should I write my trigger.